# How to make right column of two column grid overflow into the left column

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

Unsure if the title is descriptive enough, but what I currently have is this:

[image: picture of current solution]

with HTML and CSS:

```css
.test-outer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  column-gap: 1rem;
}

.test-left {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  height: 6.28rem;
}

.test-right {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  row-gap: 1rem;
  column-gap: 1rem;
}

.test-right-item {
  background-color: #999;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-outer">
  <div class="test-left">
    0
  </div>
  <div class="test-right">
    <div class="test-right-item">
      1<br>2
    </div>
    <div class="test-right-item">
      3<br>4
    </div>
    <div class="test-right-item">
      5<br>6
    </div>
    <div class="test-right-item">
      7<br>8
    </div>
    <div class="test-right-item">
      9<br>10
    </div>
    <div class="test-right-item">
      11<br>12
    </div>
    <div class="test-right-item">
      13<br>14
    </div>
    <div class="test-right-item">
      15<br>16
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I have fixed the height of the `.test-left` class, and would like all items in the right column that are below the fixed height of the left column to overflow into the left column. The height doesn't have to be fixed via the `height` property but is just how I've currently gotten it to the height I want. Eventually I want it to look like this:

[image]

Unfortunately I have hard coded a bunch of `div`s to be in those exact positions and would like it to do this dynamically so I can loop over an object of data via Jinja and place all the `div`s in that way. All the `div`s below the top left box will continue to grow left to right downwards.

I can imagine a solution where I loop over the first four elements in that data (if four exist, otherwise however many there are) and place them to the right of the big box, and then any elements after the first four I can loop over and are placed in a different grid below the big box, but perhaps there is a cleaner solution.

I'm okay with a solution including some JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use grid to move things around a bit giving that first item span of 2 rows and two columns.

Added a second block with less in it to show it sizes the same;

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display:grid;
  gap: 1em;
}

.test-outer {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  row-gap: 1em;
  /* just to show what is where */
  border: 2px solid #00ff00;
}

.test-right-item,
.test-left {
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  border: 2px solid black;
  /* super center the contents */
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.test-left {
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 2;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  height: 6.28em;
}

.test-right-item {
  background-color: #999;
  height: 2.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-outer">
  <div class="test-left">
    0
  </div>
  <div class="test-right-item">
    1<br>2
  </div>
  <div class="test-right-item">
    3<br>4
  </div>
  <div class="test-right-item">
    5<br>6
  </div>
  <div class="test-right-item">
    7<br>8
  </div>
  <div class="test-right-item">
    9<br>10
  </div>
  <div class="test-right-item">
    11<br>12
  </div>
  <div class="test-right-item">
    13<br>14
  </div>
  <div class="test-right-item">
    15<br>16
  </div>
</div>
<div class="test-outer">
  <div class="test-left">
    0
  </div>
  <div class="test-right-item">
    1<br>2
  </div>
  <div class="test-right-item">
    3<br>4
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `grid-row: span 2;` and `grid-column: span 2;` to first `div`:

```css
.test-outer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 1rem;
}

.test-outer div {
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #999;
}

.test-outer div:first-child {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  grid-row: span 2;
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-outer">
  <div>
    0
  </div>
  <div>
    1<br>2
  </div>
  <div>
    3<br>4
  </div>
  <div>
    5<br>6
  </div>
  <div>
    7<br>8
  </div>
  <div>
    9<br>10
  </div>
  <div>
    11<br>12
  </div>
  <div>
    13<br>14
  </div>
  <div>
    15<br>16
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

one way to do it using [`grid-row`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row) property

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr; 
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
  grid-template-rows: 1fr; 
  gap: 10px 10px; 
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr 1fr;

}

.item {
    background-color: #999;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;    
}

.item.highlight {
    background-color: aquamarine;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    height: 6.28rem;    
    grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="item highlight">
        0
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        1<br>2
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        3<br>4
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        5<br>6
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        7<br>8
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        9<br>10
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        11<br>12
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        13<br>14
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        15<br>16
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is close. I need the highlighted box to be 1/2 the width of the page though :/

Comment: why do you have `grid-template-rows:` twice in the `.parent` css?

Comment: i forgot to remove the first one !